# What is the best way of getting / using Context inside AsyncTask?

Tags: android, constructor, android-asynctask, inner-classes, android-context

I've defined a separate thread by extending the `AsyncTask` class. Within this class I perform some Toasts and Dialogs within the AsyncTask's `onPostExecute` and `onCancelled` methods. The toasts require the application's context such that all I need do is:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Some String",1);
```

The dialogs are created using `AlertDialog.Builder` which also requires a context in its constructor. Am I right in thinking that this context should be the Activity's context? i.e.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

where `getActivity` could be a user defined class that returns the current activity. If so what is the best way to handle this situation? Creating a class like `getActivity` or passing the current activity's context to the AsyncTask's constructor?

I guess I'm trying to understand the use of `Context` - I have noticed that memory leaks can be an issue (don't really understand this yet) and how using `getApplicationContext()` is the best approach where possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply create the AsyncTask as an **inner class** of your Activity, or **pass the Context** to the Constructor of the AsyncTask.

**Inner class:** MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    // your other methods of the activity here...


    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

         protected Void doInBackground(Void... param) {

             publishProgress(...);  // this will call onProgressUpdate();
         }

         protected Void onProgressUpdate(Void... prog) {

             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "text", 1000).show(); 
         }
    }
}
```

**Constructor:** MyTask.java

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

     Context c;

     public MyTask(Context c) {
          this.c = c;
     }

     protected Void doInBackground(Void... param) {

          publishProgress(...);  // this will call onProgressUpdate();
     }

     protected Void onProgressUpdate(Void... prog) {
          Toast.makeText(c, "text", 1000).show();
     }
}
```

Furthermore, please do not forget to **call .show() on your Dialog**.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.show();
```

Comment: Thanks Phil. My AsyncTask is currently an inner class of my activity (as you show above). However, whilst this works for `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ...` in `MyTask`'s UI methods, `AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())` does not work. I presume this is because it is not getting the right context?  Therefore, is it not a requirement to pass the activity's context to `MyTask`'s constructor? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Could you post the full code of where you make your dialog? Also do not forget to call .show() on the Dialog.

Comment: Okay, yes! Both `Toast` and `AlertDialog` work when passing the context to `MyTask`'s constructor as you have shown above, i.e., instantiating `MyTask` using `MyTask(this)` from an onClick event in the main activity. Right, so I just need to clarify: `MyTask(this)` passes the activity's context to `MyTask` which can be used by both `Toast` and `AlertDialog`. However, whilst `Toast` can use the applications context using `getApplicationContext()`, `AlertDialog` cannot, i.e., it needs the activity's context - think that's where I was going wrong.

Comment: Marked as correct! Need more points apparently to rate it :(. Cheers Phil

Comment: I think the answer is incorrect, at last the Toast can't be call in background.

Comment: Done, dusted, sorted!

Comment: Well to be 100% correct you should probably call the toast from the onProgressUpdate() method. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes. TeeTracker you're correct: `doInBackground` doesn't run on the UI thread. I was calling from `onCancelled` and `onPostExecute`.

Comment: How is this example not a memory leak on the context ?  What if the activity gets destroyed, the inner asyncTask is still holding a strong reference to the  context so it can be garbage collected, right ?